# Why am I getting different results from two forms of the same math expression [javascript]?

Tags: javascript

Knowing that:    x^2 - 4y^2 = (x - 2y)*(x + 2y)

[image]

I wrote the following code:

```js
x = 450000005;
y = 225000002;
n = x * x - 4 * y * y;
m = (x - 2 * y) * (x + 2 * y);
console.log(n, m);
```

And the output is:

```
900000032 900000009
```

So what happens inside JavaScript that makes these two expressions have different results?
(It doesn't happen for all numbers!)

Comment: Can't see that equation with dark SO theme

Comment: I'm using black background and that image is almost unreadable...

Comment: [Just to illustrate the unreadablity](https://i.imgur.com/K8yQTGc.png)

Comment: @phuzi sorry i didn't know how to write formulas so i used an image

Comment: @Ehsan what's wrong with just typing it? `x^2 - 4y^2 = (x - 2y)*(x + 2y)`

Comment: That's fine but please don't use image with transparent background

Comment: @vlaz i'll add that for future reference. thanks!

Comment: Just an unrelated tip, the JavaScript [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) would more accurately reflect your formula in JavaScript. (also, you weren't actually using undeclared variables, right?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first calculation is exceeding [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), which means it cannot be accurately represented. Using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s instead will produce the correct results.

```js
console.log("Is 450000005 * 450000005 (x * x) safe?",
  Number.isSafeInteger(450000005 * 450000005));
x = 450000005n;
y = 225000002n;
n = x * x - 4n * y * y;
m = (x - 2n * y) * (x + 2n * y);
console.log(n.toString(), m.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

The numbers you're using are too high for JavaScript's implementation of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to be accurate at the less significant figures. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

which `x * x` (among other expressions) surpasses.

Use BigInts instead:

```js
x = 450000005n;
y = 225000002n;
n = x * x - 4n * y * y;
m = (x - 2n * y) * (x + 2n * y);
console.log(String(n), String(m));
```

Comment: Well, it's not particularly JavaScript's implementation, especially considering that JavaScript does not have a single implementation, but multiple runtimes, it's just the standard in general, and how much can be fit in a 64-bit floating point number.